# ORACLE: Used main memory by a sql statement

Tags: oracle, memory, program-entry-point

Is it possible to get the used main memory which a normal sql statement needs? I try to understand how explain plans works and i find the PLAN_TABLE which contains the explain plans, but I'm not sure if the PLAN_TABLE gives information about the used memory.

Comment: CPU_COST and IO_COST: Yes.  Specific RAM usage for a given query: no:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm

Comment: To get the cpu_cost of the statement, i have to calculate the sum for each row. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

PLAN_TABLE holds the information from an [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601) statement, being the execution plan that your query will likely follow when executed. Actual execution statistics may be totally different than what was expected in advance. If you're looking for actual used memory, PLAN_TABLE is not good enough. Actual execution statistics can be obtained from [V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS_ALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3057.htm). These are nicely printed with the function [dbms_xplan.display_cursor](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/03/dbmsxplandisplaycursor.html). It shows you "Used-Mem" in the MEMSTATS section. Or you may want to examine the dynamic view [V$SESSTAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3028.htm#i1416128).

Regards,
Rob.